# How to correctly perform arithmetic on classes instances? E.g. Sum the n_people attribute for a list of House class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance-variables

How to correctly perform arithmetic on classes instances? In the below example the class represents a `House` and contains an `n_people` attribute representing the number of people in that house.

The objective is to perform a sum on the `House` class instances and return the total number of people in the houses. This seems to work when the `House` class instances are added together:

```
class House:

    def __init__(self, n_people):
        self.n_people = n_people

    def __add__(self, n_people):
        return n_people + self.n_people

House(3) + House(4)
```

And fails when an array of `House` class instances is being summed:

```
houses = [House(i) for i in range(10)]
sum(houses)
```

The resulting error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-197f26932b89> in <module>
      1 houses = [House(i) for i in range(10)]
----> 2 sum(houses)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'House'
```

What is the correct way to perform arithmetic on class instances in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `sum` works left-to-right, so after the first two `House` instances are summed, your code tries to perform `int + House`, when only `House + int` is defined.

To solve this, you need to define `__radd__`, which gets called in that situation:

```
class House:

    def __init__(self, n_people):
        self.n_people = n_people

    def __add__(self, n_people):
        return n_people + self.n_people

    def __radd__(self, n_people):
        return n_people + self.n_people

House(3) + House(4)
houses = [House(i) for i in range(10)]
sum(houses)
```

Output:

```
45
```